# Input splits for map tasks are coming from different nodes along with the current node

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I read that map tasks usually run on the data residing on the same node for optimization reasons.  But in my job tracker (hadoop admininstration page), i could see that the input split locations for a map task running in, say node1, are from node3, node1 and node4.  I have totally 10 map tasks spawned and for some of them the input split location points to 3 different nodes other than the map task's node.  Is this common and ok? Is it related to how I load my input files into hdfs and that they are equally distributed in the cluster?  If this is not ok, how do i make sure the map tasks pick the data from the same node as far as possible?

Comment: That'll be your replication coming in to play if I'm not mistaken. You can turn it off if you want full control over where your data resides but risk its integrity as if you corrupt/lose/etc that copy the data is ruined/lost forever, no backups.

Comment: map is supposed to read input from the same node as far as possible.  Replication of the same input split could be present in other nodes, but when the data is available in the same node, why should map read it from another node which is expensive and could affect performance?  As in the example i told in the question, I could see input splits from node1 being used by map running in other nodes

Comment: (...continuation of previous comment) and map task at node1 is using splits from other nodes.  Why cant map run with the splits in the same node?  how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are some of your tasks taking longer than the others?If that is the case `speculative execution` will come into the picture which is probably the reason behind this.

Tasks may be slow for various reasons, including hardware degradation or software mis-configuration, but the causes may be hard to detect since the tasks still complete successfully, albeit after a longer time than expected. Hadoop doesn’t try to diagnose and fix slow-running tasks; instead, it tries to detect when a task is running slower than expected and launches another, equivalent, task as a backup. This is termed `speculative execution` of tasks.

Speculative execution is turned on by default. However, it can be enabled or disabled independently for map tasks and reduce tasks, on a cluster-wide basis, or on a per-job basis.

Hope this answers the question.

P.S. : Speculative execution is an optimization, not a feature to make jobs run more reliably. If there are bugs that sometimes cause a task to hang or slow down, then relying on speculative execution to avoid these problems is unwise, and won’t work reliably, since the same bugs are likely to affect the speculative task. You should fix the bug so that the task doesn’t hang or slow down.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.  All my map tasks completes within 2 to 3 minutes. But yes, all of my reduce tasks finishes in 3 minutes, while one or two reduce tasks takes around 9 mins to complete.  I have already set `job.setReduceSpeculativeExecution(true);`  But how is this related to input split allocation to map task?

Comment: SpeculativeExecution makes sure that a map task gets started for each replica of a block on all the machines where these replicas are present. The task which gets completed first returns the result and rest of the tasks retire.

Comment: ok.  So do you mean that, if i turn off speculative execution, then the map tasks would read input splits from its respective nodes?  Thanks for your patience!

Comment: yes. map will start on anyone of the nodes where that particular block is present based on the availability of slots. not a prob.